# New Project Wizard error in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio

This is what I get when I try to create a new Android Studio project:

```
com.android.builder.model.AndroidLibrary.getProject()Ljava/lang/String;

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

Using the latest androidStudio, `0.2.8`.

I can't even open any project to see my logs.

Comment: Check whether your working project folder path has any quotation marks or any stupid characters. Android Studio doesn't seem to like those.

Answer (score 0):

just update the `ADT` and the `Android SDK Manager`.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what OS you are using, you can view the log file from your home directory

> '.AndroidStudioPreview\system\log\idea.log'